# select ... not exists not exists query

Tags: sql, t-sql, exists

```
select r.index, sum(c.points)
from records r join exams e2 on r.index = e2.index
    join courses c on c.id_course = e2.id_course
where not exists ( select *
                    from required_courses rs
                    where rs.id_studie = r.id_studie
                        and not exists (select *
                                        from exams e
                                        where e.id_course = rs.id_course
                                            and r.index = e.index
                                            and score>5))
    and score>5
group by index;
```

I have that query. I know what it does, but don't know how.

I have relativly big database with 16 tables, but only use 4 in this query.
Used tables are:

1. RECORDS (of students) [index (pr. key), name, surname, ..., id_studie(1)(for. key)]
2. EXAMS [index(of students) (p.k.), id_course(p.k.),..., score(2), application_status]
3. COURSES [id_course(p.k.), ..., points]
4. REQUIRED_COURSES [id_studie (f.k.), id_course(f.k), ...]

(1) I don't know better word in English. When on some faculty there are Informatics, Math, Physics, etc. classes. Informatics is one studie.
(2) Scores go from 5 to 10. 10 is best. At least 6 is required for passing.

**Query:**
-  Find all students that passed all required exams on studie thay studie. Print indexes and number of points.

My question: Can sameone explain how does this work in simple words?

I don't understand not exists & not exists part.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I think this article by Joe Celko might help you: [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: This is **really** helpfull. Thank you very much.
I didn't know this is called division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always analyze the query from the inside out.

Innermost query:
Select the exams with score higher than 5

Middle one:

Select the required courses that don't have an exam with score higher than 5

Outer one:

Select students that don't have a required course that doesn't have the exam with score higher than 5

Comment: I can't give you +1 because I don't have enough reputation, but this is what I asked for - simple explanation.
I'm not sure if I know how to write it, but at least I now get it.

Answer (score 1):

The example is a double-nested `NOT EXISTS` query.

If a subquery returns any rows at all, `EXISTS` subquery is `TRUE`, and `NOT EXISTS` subquery is `FALSE`.

That is, it has a `NOT EXISTS` clause within a `NOT EXISTS` clause.

It is easier to say that a nested `NOT EXISTS` answers the question “is x TRUE for all y?”

```
--Part 3
SELECT r.index, 
       SUM(c.points) 
FROM   records r 
       join exams e2 
         ON r.index = e2.index 
       join courses c 
         ON c.id_course = e2.id_course 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
--Part 2 starts
                   SELECT * 
                   FROM   required_courses rs 
                   WHERE  rs.id_studie = r.id_studie 
                          AND NOT EXISTS (
--Part 1 starts                                         
                                          SELECT * 
                                          FROM   exams e 
                                          WHERE  e.id_course = rs.id_course 
                                                 AND r.index = e.index 
                                                 AND score > 5
--Part 1 ends
                                                              )
--Part 2 ends                                         
                                                               )
       AND score > 5 
GROUP  BY index; 
--Part 3 ends
```

**Part 1:** Fetch all records of students from EXAMS table who scored more than 5. You should get all pass mark students for all courses here

**Part 2:** Join Part1 results with `REQUIRED_COURSES` on student id and fetch all the required courses where the student has not cleared the exams (where student does not have a score more than 5). You should have all the student's courses name where they are not successful

**Part 3:** Join Part 2 results with `RECORDS` table on index and also `COURSES` table on course id to fetch the index and sum of points. You can see this part into two pieces. First is the normal `JOIN` with two tables and then the `NOT EXISTS` with the part 2. When you apply a `NOT EXISTS` on part 2, you are going to get all successful student ids which would provide you the successful entries by adding another `SCORE > 5` condition at the end.